# HTML/CSS List image issue

Tags: html, css

I have put a picture in the HTML code which is inside a ul/li list now what happens is that the picture gets the correct description on the right however the next bullet point is also next to the picture which i want to avoid ... (see example image below )

The coding for this I used is :

```
<ul>
  <li><strong>Dwarf</strong></li>
</ul>

<img src="C:\Users\690177\Desktop\TEST WEB\images\troll.jpg">

The dwarf figurine is short, stocky and well armored, carrying a battle axe. He is very good in health, but lacks the attack strength of the barbarian and has no magical abilities. The dwarf also has the unique ability of being able to disarm traps without special equipment. His starting weapon is a short sword.</p>

<ul>
  <li><strong>Elf</strong></li>
</ul> 

The elf figurine is tall and slender, armed with a short one-handed sword. He is equal in attack strength to the dwarf, but is less physically robust. He is also able to use one element's spell—air, earth, fire, or water magic, and can resist magical attack more effectively. His starting weapon is a short sword.
```

and also a separate CSS file with :

```
img {
  float: left;
  height:90px;
  width:75px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: try this: li {overflow: hidden;}

Comment: Also, don't link to a screenshot, instead create a fiddle on this site that recreates the problem.

Comment: Thx for quick response , does not work it just removes the 'dots' of the list ...

Comment: Why dont you use bootstrap?

Comment: Now that i look at it... I don't think your code makes sense. What's the point of having a list with only 1 li inside of it?

Comment: There are more i just copied a bit as an example

Comment: What does bootstrap provide ? a template or ... based on the comment why to use bootstrap ? 
Sorry I am only doing HTML for like 2 days

Comment: @LaMat Your `<img>` tag isn't inside of the list. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @BDawg If I do the tag inside the list then it overflows again with the Dwarf bullet point ... now the result is better and cleaner

Comment: @LaMat "Better" depends on your perspective. Your HTML needs a bit of work. (See the answer I provided below for more details) For only 2 days of experience, though, you're doing really well!

Comment: Thank you all for the comments , I have used some bootstrap code to get it all worked out :) ... slow but steady :D

Answer (score 1):

In case the two `ul` elements are really what you need: You can just clear the float on the `ul` elements:

```
ul {
  clear: both;
}
```

This way, the existing float from the image ist stopped and not affecting the next list anymore. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) for more information about the clear property.

Normally you would just use one list `ul` with multiple list items `li`. See @BDawg's answer for this.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <strong>Dwarf</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
<img src="C:\Users\690177\Desktop\TEST WEB\images\troll.jpg">The dwarf figurine is short, stocky and well armored, carrying a battle axe. He is very good in health, but lacks the attack strength of the barbarian and has no magical abilities. The dwarf also has the unique ability of being able to disarm traps without
special equipment. His starting weapon is a short sword.
<ul>
  <li><strong>Elf</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
The elf figurine is tall and slender, armed with a short one-handed sword. He is equal in attack strength to the dwarf, but is less physically robust. He is also able to use one element's spell—air, earth, fire, or water magic, and can resist magical
attack more effectively. His starting weapon is a short sword. and also a separate CSS file with :
```

Comment: Worked :) Thx 

I am only just started with this HTML/CSS thing , I have the link of bootstrap at home and I will try this at home , does bootstrap do this automatically or does it provide a good template for this ?

Comment: Bootstrap has the `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes to float elements. If you use Bottstraps container/row system, you won't need this clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

**The CSS property you are looking for is `clear: both;`**

Also, your HTML isn't structured semantically - that is, the meaning of the code doesn't make sense. You have a list of figurines, so there should only be one single `<ul>` list. See the snippet below for a better example of HTML structure.

```css
li {
  clear: both;
}

img {
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><strong>Dwarf</strong></div>
    <img src="C:\Users\690177\Desktop\TEST WEB\images\troll.jpg">
    <p>The dwarf figurine is short, stocky and well armored, carrying a battle axe. He is very good in health, but lacks the attack strength of the barbarian and has no magical abilities. The dwarf also has the unique ability of being able to disarm traps without special equipment. His starting weapon is a short sword.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><strong>Elf</strong></div>
    <p>The elf figurine is tall and slender, armed with a short one-handed sword. He is equal in attack strength to the dwarf, but is less physically robust. He is also able to use one element's spell—air, earth, fire, or water magic, and can resist magical attack more effectively. His starting weapon is a short sword.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```